# Change foreground color when list item is highlighted (using SwiftUI on macOS)

Tags: macos, listview, swiftui, highlight

In a macOS app I have a `List`, the listed views (named `MyItem` here) are using the `.primary` and `.secondary` colors but also other colors like `.orange` or `.blue`.

The important thing here is: `.primary` and `.secondary` colors are automatically converted to white when the item is highlighted or selected, but the other colors are not.

Naively, I added a `selected: Bool` property to `MyItem` and when the list reports it as selected I manually convert the colors to white, something like this:

```swift
struct MyItem: View {
    var selected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello").foregroundColor(.primary)
        Text("World").foregroundColor(selected ? .white : .orange)
    }
}

struct MyList: View {
    @State private var selectedItemId: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, selection: $selectedItemId) { item in
            MyItem(selected: selectedItemId == item.id)
        }
    }
}
```

It works great when using the keyboard, but once you start selecting items with the mouse, you see this workaround doesn't work with highlighted items. Here's an example where I start by using the keyboard and next I show how the colors are not changed when highlighting the items with the mouse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X07mB0OsTQk

I've searched everywhere, from SwiftUI's documentation to Cocoa's, including AppKit's, I couldn't find an easy way to change the color when the item is highlighted… Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm missing something, but I can't see what is not changing in your video, between mouse and keyboard.

Comment: When I'm holding the mouse click and moving it (when holding you see a circle around the cursor), you can see the images are not switching colors until I stop clicking.

Comment: Provide a minimum reproducible example, you code has missing parts